# Screenshot of multiple webpages in a headerless QtWebKit browser in Python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I am attempting to render multiple webpages and taking screenshots of them, but I can only get it to work when rendering one webpage, because when I try it on multiple the program will either stop dead in it's tracks and hang forever OR just not do anything with images, css and will extract the text of the site and put it in one long block of text. Usually what's happening is it will hang.

Code I'm using to render the webpage in memory is this:

```
class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)

        # Settings
        s = self.settings()
        #s.setAttribute(QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, False)
        s.setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptCanOpenWindows, False)
        s.setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)

        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        #self.mainFrame().setScrollBarPolicy(Qt.Vertical, Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.mainFrame().setScrollBarPolicy(Qt.Horizontal, Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        size = self.frame.contentsSize()
        size.setWidth(1366)
        self.setViewportSize(size)
        self.app.quit()
```

And here's how I'm saving the image:

```
def run(url):
    os.chdir("output")

    r = Render(url)
    image = QImage(r.viewportSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    painter = QPainter(image)
    r.frame.render(painter)
    painter.end()
    fp = "%s.png" % os_safe_name(url)
    image.save(fp)
    os.chdir("..")
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much as described in Luke's answer, I shuffled things around to avoid creating a `QApplication` instance for each `Render`

Not the tidiest, but works for me:

```
import re
import sys
import time

# Tested with PySide 1.0.9, changing imports to PyQt should work identically
from PySide.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QImage, QPainter
from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebPage, QWebSettings


def os_safe_name(url):
    url = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]+", "_", url)
    url = re.sub("_{2,}", "_", url)
    return url


class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        QWebPage.__init__(self)

        self.url = url
        self.finished = False

        # Settings
        s = self.settings()
        #s.setAttribute(QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, False)
        s.setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptCanOpenWindows, False)
        s.setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)

        #self.mainFrame().setScrollBarPolicy(Qt.Vertical, Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.mainFrame().setScrollBarPolicy(Qt.Horizontal, Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        # When page is loaded, callback saves image to file
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)

        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        frame = self.mainFrame()
        size = frame.contentsSize()
        size.setWidth(1366)
        self.setViewportSize(size)

        image = QImage(self.viewportSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)

        painter = QPainter(image)
        frame.render(painter)
        painter.end()

        self.filepath = "output/%s.png" % os_safe_name(self.url)
        image.save(self.filepath)

        self.finished = True


def run(url, app = None):
    if app is None:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    r = Render(url)

    while not r.finished:
        app.processEvents()
        time.sleep(0.01)

    return r.filepath


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    print run("http://stackoverflow.com", app=app)
    print run("http://google.com", app=app)
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you. This answer is more complete so I'm accepting it.

Comment: This doesn't sound correct for taking snapshots as it doesn't disable the sound. For example, if you load this page: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kK42LZqO0wA and want to wait a bit (so as to let the comments load, for example), you will be able to hear the HTML5 video playing. How can you avoid this?

Comment: @user9379 I don't think there's an easy way to do that.. What the plugins do is outside of Qt's control - the plugin will communicate directly with the operating system's audio subsystem

Comment: @user9379 There will be platform-specific means to redirect audio from a specific process, things like AudioHijack on OS X, Jack on Linux and Windows has a specific API for application-volume-control somewhere

Comment: @dbr I am actually trying to make an advanced Qt library for website snapshots and this is my only problem... Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are creating multiple instances of your Render class. If this is the case, then you are most likely having problems because you create multiple QApplication instances. Instead, create a single QApplication and share it between all of your Render instances.

You'll also probably need to stop using app.quit() since you want the QApplication to continue functioning. Furthermore, since app.exec_() won't exit until you call quit(), you'll need to make your own event loop instead. Something like this:

```
while not self.finished:
    self.app.processEvents()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```